# Heatmap using ggplot for 300+ units

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, heatmap

I am trying to generate a heatmap via ggplot using the following code I found online (https://simplystatistics.org/2019/08/28/you-can-replicate-almost-any-plot-with-ggplot2/):

```
library(dslabs)
data(us_contagious_diseases)
the_disease <- "Measles"
dat <- us_contagious_diseases %>%
  filter(!state%in%c("Hawaii","Alaska") & disease == the_disease) %>%
  mutate(rate = count / population * 10000 * 52 / weeks_reporting) 

jet.colors <- colorRampPalette(c("#F0FFFF", "cyan", "#007FFF", "yellow", "#FFBF00", "orange", "red", "#7F0000"), bias = 2.25)

dat %>% mutate(state = reorder(state, desc(state))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, state, fill = rate)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white", size = 0.35) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = jet.colors(16), na.value = 'white') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1963, col = "black") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
        coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
        ggtitle(the_disease) +
        ylab("") +
        xlab("") +  
        theme(legend.position = "bottom", text = element_text(size = 8)) + 
        annotate(geom = "text", x = 1963, y = 50.5, label = "Vaccine introduced", size = 3, hjust = 0)
```

Result:
[image]

This all works fine but in my dataset I have 320 units instead of 50. I have created a similar scenario using the data from the example above:

```
library(dslabs)
data(us_contagious_diseases)
the_disease <- "Measles"
dat <- us_contagious_diseases %>%
  filter(!state%in%c("Hawaii","Alaska") & disease == the_disease) %>%
  mutate(rate = count / population * 10000 * 52 / weeks_reporting) 

dat1 <- dat

levels(dat1$state) <- c("State1_1","State1_2","State1_3","State1_4","State1_5","State1_6","State1_7","State1_8","State1_9","State1_10",
                        "State1_11","State1_12","State1_13","State1_14","State1_15","State1_16","State1_17","State1_18","State1_19","State1_20",
                        "State1_21","State1_22","State1_23","State1_24","State1_25","State1_26","State1_27","State1_28","State1_29","State1_30",
                        "State1_31","State1_32","State1_33","State1_34","State1_35","State1_36","State1_37","State1_38","State1_39","State1_40",             
                        "State1_41","State1_42","State1_43","State1_44","State1_45","State1_46","State1_47","State1_48","State1_49","State1_50","State1_51")                      

dat2 <- dat

levels(dat2$state) <- c("State2_1","State2_2","State2_3","State2_4","State2_5","State2_6","State2_7","State2_8","State2_9","State2_10",
                        "State2_11","State2_12","State2_13","State2_14","State2_15","State2_16","State2_17","State2_18","State2_19","State2_20",
                        "State2_21","State2_22","State2_23","State2_24","State2_25","State2_26","State2_27","State2_28","State2_29","State2_30",
                        "State2_31","State2_32","State2_33","State2_34","State2_35","State2_36","State2_37","State2_38","State2_39","State2_40",             
                        "State2_41","State2_42","State2_43","State2_44","State2_45","State2_46","State2_47","State2_48","State2_49","State2_50","State2_51")                      

dat3 <- dat

levels(dat3$state) <- c("State3_1","State3_2","State3_3","State3_4","State3_5","State3_6","State3_7","State3_8","State3_9","State3_10",
                        "State3_11","State3_12","State3_13","State3_14","State3_15","State3_16","State3_17","State3_18","State3_19","State3_20",
                        "State3_21","State3_22","State3_23","State3_24","State3_25","State3_26","State3_27","State3_28","State3_29","State3_30",
                        "State3_31","State3_32","State3_33","State3_34","State3_35","State3_36","State3_37","State3_38","State3_39","State3_40",             
                        "State3_41","State3_42","State3_43","State3_44","State3_45","State3_46","State3_47","State3_48","State3_49","State3_50","State3_51")                      

dat4 <- dat

levels(dat4$state) <- c("State4_1","State4_2","State4_3","State4_4","State4_5","State4_6","State4_7","State4_8","State4_9","State4_10",
                        "State4_11","State4_12","State4_13","State4_14","State4_15","State4_16","State4_17","State4_18","State4_19","State4_20",
                        "State4_21","State4_22","State4_23","State4_24","State4_25","State4_26","State4_27","State4_28","State4_29","State4_30",
                        "State4_31","State4_32","State4_33","State4_34","State4_35","State4_36","State4_37","State4_38","State4_39","State4_40",             
                        "State4_41","State4_42","State4_43","State4_44","State4_45","State4_46","State4_47","State4_48","State4_49","State4_50","State4_51")                      

dat5 <- dat

levels(dat5$state) <- c("State5_1","State5_2","State5_3","State5_4","State5_5","State5_6","State5_7","State5_8","State5_9","State5_10",
                        "State5_11","State5_12","State5_13","State5_14","State5_15","State5_16","State5_17","State5_18","State5_19","State5_20",
                        "State5_21","State5_22","State5_23","State5_24","State5_25","State5_26","State5_27","State5_28","State5_29","State5_30",
                        "State5_31","State5_32","State5_33","State5_34","State5_35","State5_36","State5_37","State5_38","State5_39","State5_40",             
                        "State5_41","State5_42","State5_43","State5_44","State5_45","State5_46","State5_47","State5_48","State5_49","State5_50","State5_51")                      

dat <- rbind(dat,dat1,dat2,dat3,dat4,dat5)
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette(c("#F0FFFF", "cyan", "#007FFF", "yellow", "#FFBF00", "orange", "red", "#7F0000"), bias = 2.25)

dat %>% mutate(state = reorder(state, desc(state))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, state, fill = rate)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white", size = 0.35) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = jet.colors(16), na.value = 'white') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1963, col = "black") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  ggtitle(the_disease) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +  
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", text = element_text(size = 8)) + 
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1963, y = 50.5, label = "Vaccine introduced", size = 3, hjust = 0)
```

Result:

[image]

In this case, the heatmap is too long and no longer can be seen on the screen without scrolling down. Any ideas on how to fit all these 320 units on the screen without making the squares too small?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to show here. 320 data points is simply too much for a human observer to understand anyway. Even the original heatmap that you’re using as inspiration [has been criticised on datavis grounds](https://www.nxn.se/valent/modelling-measles-in-20th-century-us). In general, the answer will be: summarise the data, plot the summaries.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. Not sure I understand the criticism from the link you shared. I explored the link and saw a different way of presenting the data, but didn't see it as a criticism to the the heatmap. What is the problem with the heatmap?

Comment: The issue is the missing summary. The heatmap versions of this plot all display the 50-odd states as individual data points, but they do not provide a visualisation of a statistical summary. This makes the measles plot especially hard to interpret because it shows no causal relationship between the case numbers and the introduction of the vaccine. All it shows is a drop “some time afterwards” (nor does it show the striking constancy in case numbers). By contrast, including a summary statistic clearly shows that the drop in cases starts *immediately* with the vaccine introduction.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. May I just clarify something - what do you mean by a visualisation of a "statistical summary"? In the link you shared, I don't think there is a statistical summary in any of those plots? I am trying to understand what you meant by "including a summary statistic clearly shows that the drop in cases starts immediately with the vaccine introduction".

Comment: The very first plot contains a statistical summary: the yellow regression line.

Answer (score 0):

There is a practical limit to how useful this is, based on screen (or paper size). It looks like you are coming up against that limit.

You could rotate the plot, since screens tend to be wider than they are high, but that upsets the obvious left-to-right chronology of your plot.

I think your only other realistic options would be to either split the plot up by some other variable, or summarise the categories on the y axis in some way, and hide most of the labels on the y axis. In the example you've created, you could group them as geographic regions rather than individual states e.g. East coast, West coast, South, etc. Whatever works for your real data. If all the labels on the y axis are important, then the plot has to be split up, because they are essentially unreadable as it currently stands.